# Show that $|a|>|b|/2$ knowing that $|a−b|<|b|/2$.

Tags: absolute-value

I'm working on a proof and I need to show that $|a|>|b|/2$ knowing that $|a-b|<|b|/2$. I would like to do it without enumerating the different cases.

Thanks for you ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality in the 2nd inequality below:
$$
\frac{|b|}{2}>|a-b|=|b-a|\geq|b|-|a|\implies |a|>|b|-\frac{|b|}{2}=\frac{|b|}{2}.
$$

**Edit**: a few more details: the triangle inequality states that:
$$
|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|.
$$
So applying it with $x=b-a$ and $y=a$ yields
$$
|b|=|b-a+a|\leq |b-a|+|a|\implies|b-a|\geq|b|-|a|.
$$

Comment: In fact you use the reverse triangle inequality $|a-b|\geq |(|a|-|b|)|$ but how did you drop the outside absolute value of the right hand side?

Comment: OK, thanks for your edit.